# Обработка HTTP CONNECT на proxy-сервере

Tags: c++, visual-c++, http, https, httpurlconnection

Здравствуйте!

Пишу свой proxy-сервер на C++. Изучил все man`ы и стандарты. Реализовал поддержу абсолютно всех методов запросов которые подразумевает протокол HTTP от GET до DELETE и вот столкнулся с проблемой обработки метода CONNECT. Абсолютно не могу понять как его правильно обрабатывать и пересылать между клиентом и сервером. Если с HTTP запросами все просто - пришел запрос такого вида:

```
GET http://examples.ru/i/20140904/source.js HTTP/1.1
Host: examples.ru
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

Мы из него делаем следующее:

```
GET /i/20140904/source.js HTTP/1.1
Host: examples.ru
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
```

И отправляем это дело на 80 порт и ждем ответа. Считываем ответ и закрываем соединение если кто-либо из абонентов указал "Connection: close" или если сервер больше недоступен. Я так открывал соединение вообще только на обработку 1 запроса и закрывал его после получения ответа от сервера.

Но вот я столкнулся с CONNECT, приходит запрос вида:

```
CONNECT www.google.ru:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.ru
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36
```

Ясное дело, что я его переделываю следующим образом:

```
CONNECT / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.ru
Connection: keep-alive
```

И далее отправляю клиенту код 200 Connection Established. Получаю от клиента данные, которые перенаправляю на сервер на 443 порт. В следующий момент между клиентом и сервером должны произойти рукопожатия, что видимо и происходит - в ответ от сервера приходит абракадабра, которую я пересылаю клиенту, в ответ от клиента я получаю такую же абракадабру, которую при попытке отправить серверу возникает ошибка в функции **send()** под номером **10053 - WSAECONNABORTED**. И вот я так до конца и не могу понять как правильно все-таки обработать CONNECT метод HTTP.

Объясните, пожалуйста, подробно как его обрабатывать. 
Спасибо.

Вот, собственно код того, как я обрабатываю CONNECT.

```
 // Выше принимается запрос и парсится.
 // Создаем внешний сокет с сервером.
 t_error = createSocketClient( ThisClient );
 if ( t_error == -1 ) return -1;

 t_error = sendStatusCodeToClient(ThisClient, 200);
 if ( t_error == -1 ) return -1;

 while ( true ) {
     // Прием запроса от клиента и передача серверу.
     while ( true ) {
         bytes_recv = recv(ThreadInfo[ThisClient].ClientSocket, &buffer[0], SIZE_BLOCK_4096, 0);
         if ( bytes_recv > 0 ) {
             flagData = true;
             bytes_send = send(ThreadInfo[ThisClient].ServerSocket, &buffer[0], bytes_recv, 0);
             if ( bytes_send == SOCKET_ERROR ) { 
                 return -1;
             }
         }
         else if ( bytes_recv == 0 ) break;
         else return -2;
     }

     if ( flagData == true )    {
         // Прием ответа от сервера и передача клиенту.
         while ( true ) {
             bytes_recv = recv(ThreadInfo[ThisClient].ServerSocket, &buffer[0], SIZE_BLOCK_8192, 0);
             if ( bytes_recv > 0 ) {
                 bytes_send = send(ThreadInfo[ThisClient].ClientSocket, &buffer[0], bytes_recv, 0);
                 if ( bytes_send == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
                     return -3;
                 }
             }
             else if ( bytes_recv == 0 )    break;
             else return -4;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: что-нибудь [в этом духе](https://mitmproxy.org/doc/howmitmproxy.html) не читали?

Comment: Ну так я так и делаю. Приходит CONNECT, на него, если я смог приконнектиться к указанному серверу отсылаю клиенту отклик 200 Connection Established, следом отсылаю то, что прислал мне клиент серверу, на что получаю от сервера ответ, который там под цифрой 5 и отсылаю это клиенту, от клиента получаю 6 и стоит мне это отослать серверу как я получаю ошибку в send() под номером 10053. Это же должна быть, я так понимаю, одна сессия подключения.

Comment: на Вики тоже есть небольшое пояснение https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel

Answer (score 1):

Одной из причин, может быть то, что firewall блокирует https соединения, либо любой непонятный ему исходящий трафик.
Либо ошибка в логике программы, которая закрывает сокет во время сессии, выводите в логи свои действия и увидите так ли это.

Answer (score 0):

А по моему все проще, на connect не надо ничего посылать на удаленный сервер. Надо установить tcp соединение и в случае успеха ответить клиенту, что все ок и только клиенту.
потому как в данной tcp сессии сначала пройдет рукопожатие и только после этого клиент сам пошлет в шифрованный канал свой GET или что он там хотел сделать

Answer (score 0):

Да, Майк правильно описал, при методе CONNECT обмен заголовками происходит только с клиентом, вышестоящему прокси или сайту ничего из заголовков не отправляеться. Порядок:

1. Клиент присылает запрос (как у вас в примере)
2. Ваш прокси сервер открывает сокет с ендпоинтом из этого запроса, предварительно отрезолвив имя хоста из запроса в ип адрес.
3. Если все прошло успешно, ваш прокси должен отослать клиенту ответ 200 Connection Established.
4. Весь обмен после этого, прокси транслирует все данные между клиентом и ендпоинтом.

Этот сценарий для клиента с явно прописанным прокси сервером, если использовать 'прозрачный прокси' с помощью iptables, tproxy итд, то порядок сокращается на пункт 3, клиенту не передаётся ответ 200, в случае если его запрос был не методом CONNECT. В случае с технологиями 'прозрачного проксирования' адрес ендпоинта береться из сокета, путем getsockopt надо указать флаги SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST. Если использовать технологию [TPROXY](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt), необходимо применять следующую конструкция для снятия адреса: setsockopt, SOL_IP, IP_TRANSPARENT. [пример](https://github.com/kristrev/tproxy-example).

Если это что то шифрованное, то посмотреть что там течёт не судьба :)
И обратите особое внимание на размеры при передачи как заголовков, так и данных. Неверно указанная длинна данных в HTTP хеадере влечёт обычно за собой массу проблем, с разными броузерами. И совсем кретично при трансляции шифрованный данных.